# White space in HTML links?

Tags: html

We have recently taken on a website for a client and changed the site from a PHP backend to a .aspx
which has been a real pain of a job!

Whilst adding the .aspx tags in the html code the developer has left white space within page link tags for some reason - which I have just noticed - only simple white space line breaks as shown below,  the site has been tested in ie8, firefox and Chrome and Safari on the mac and all seems fine - so it's probably just paranoia (to change all pages would take a long while) - can anyone see any major cause for concern with white space below - or should I quit being paranoid!?

```
<li><a href="../../index.html">
 home</a></li>


<a href="../../special-treats.html
"><img src="../../images/treatsbutton.gif" width="260" height="40" alt="Click here to treat    yourself" /></a>
```

Comment: doesn't ctrl + k,d fix it?

Comment: not sure I understand these comments - where would these be applied!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fine. Double white space is ignored by HTML parsers (browsers).

Comment: cool Cheers Baumr, thought so - but you've eased todays stress levels a bit!

Comment: @pablodance, glad to help. Yeah, don't worry about it — but just if you do see it as you're working on a page, it won't take much to press `Backspace`

Answer (score 1):

It will work, but it ain't pretty/fun to maintain.  My suggestion, for the sake of improved maintainability, is if you can't do them all at once, do them as you maintain it.  That is, if you're maintaining page x, clean up the breaks/whitespace on page x while you're doing it.  Spending a couple of extra minutes doing that per revision/page will make it a bit less taxing.

Comment: cool cheers shubniggurath, long as it will work for now I'm happy to clean as I go!